# How to find index at similar items during the comparing of two arrays with object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I have 2 arrays with objects.

```
const users1 = [
    { name: 'John', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Jinny', age: 30, gender: 'F', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' },
  ],

const users2 = [
        { name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' },
        { name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' },
      ],
```

I need to get index from *users1* of that parts that are contains in *users2*.

As a result I should get `[{1: true}, {3: true}]`.
I try in this way but it's not correct

```
const arr = user1.filter((item, index) => user2.map(i) => {
    if(i.id === item.id) return {index: true}
     return null;
    })
```

Comment: Wouldn't `[1, 3]` be enough for your desired result? It's a simpler structure to deal with, as the object structures of `{index: true}` feel redundant (as `true` will always be the value, and accessing the keys of an object isn't as straightforward as accessing the elements of an array)

Comment: Your objects don't have an `id` property.

Comment: In user1 and user2 items have ids. I forget to write them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of all ids from `users2` (a Set is somewhat like an array, but allows you to quickly check if a value is in it using [`.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) and it only stores unique values). Once you have the set, you can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a new array, where you can use [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) if the set has the id of the object from `users1`:

```js
const users1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'John', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'London', country: 'UK' }, { id: 2, name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' }, { id: 3, name: 'Jinny', age: 30, gender: 'F', city: 'London', country: 'UK' }, { id: 4, name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' }, ];
const users2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' }, { id: 4, name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' }, ];

const u2Ids = new Set(users2.map(user => user.id));
const res = users1.reduce((acc, obj, i) => u2Ids.has(obj.id) ? acc.concat({[i]: true}) : acc, []);
console.log(res);
```

When creating your objects you need to ensure you use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) when adding the index as a key `{[i]: true}` so that the value at `i` is used rather than the literal `i` name. The above can also be written with a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop (by accessing [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)), which is more efficient and (in my opinion) more readable:

```js
const users1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'John', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'London', country: 'UK' }, { id: 2, name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' }, { id: 3, name: 'Jinny', age: 30, gender: 'F', city: 'London', country: 'UK' }, { id: 4, name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' }, ];
const users2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' }, { id: 4, name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' }, ];

const res = [];
const u2Ids = new Set(users2.map(user => user.id));
for(const [i, obj] of users1.entries()) {
  if(u2Ids.has(obj.id))
    res.push({[i]: true});
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

First your array don't contains ids I filtered name for now.Also filter will not work here bcs if you use filter that will just filter your array and index will no longer be the same try following instead

```js
const users1 = [
    { name: 'John', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Jinny', age: 30, gender: 'F', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' }
  ];

const users2 = [
        { name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' },
        { name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' }
      ];

const arr = [];
users1.forEach((item, idx) =>{
    if(users2.some(u=> u.name == item.name)){
    arr.push({[idx]:true})
    }
    });
    console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach - with `Array.reduce()`

```
const users1 = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' },
  { name: 'Jinny', age: 30, gender: 'F', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
  { name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' },
];

const users2 = [
  { name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' },
  { name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' },
];

const arr = users1.
  reduce((previousValue, currentValue, index) => {
    // change here to find by id 
    if (users2.some(u2 => u2.name === currentValue.name) ){
      // map to whatever you want
      const valueToSave = {[index] : true};
      return [...previousValue, valueToSave];
    } else {
      return previousValue;
    }
  }, []);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

@festina, to keep it simple we map on users2, as we are trying to find objects of users1 in users2, we get index using findIndex using (id/name any unique key available) and then filter by index > 0, and format the result in required format

```
const users1 = [
 { name: 'John', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
 { name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' },
 { name: 'Jinny', age: 30, gender: 'F', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
 { name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' },
];

const users2 = [
    { name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' },
  ];
// your solution
const result = users2.map((user, index) => users1.findIndex(u => u.name === user.name))
.filter(index => index > 0)
.map((i => { return { [i]:  true} }));
console.log(result)
```